# CSS and HTML when recreating a Table and the code won't work. I don't see the error

Tags: html, css

I'm recreating a table. However, when doing this table I'm facing several roadblocks and I'm not identifying the root cause since I see everything as it's suppose to. The system is not taking the `id` of the table, hence it's also not applying the colors.

I've applied the `Border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid black` and it's not working. If I only use `Border-collapse:collapse` it collapse indeed but erase the lines.

Here is all what I'm using. (unfortunately I can't post pictures since I'm not reaching 10 yet as reputation. I hope you can help me. :) Happy weekend

```html
<head>
  <style>
      table,
    td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    th {
      background-color: teal;
      # EdenSher tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: Orchid;
      }
      #EdenSher tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: Plum;
      }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <p>Star Butterfly arrives on Earth to live with the Diazes, a Mexican-American family. She continues to battle villains throughout the universe and high school, mainly to protect her extremely powerful wand, an object that still confuses her (this is a
    text within the code).</p>

  <p>Recreate the table from the image below. Colors used include:</p>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <table id="EdenSher" style="width:600px;">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" style="background-color: lemonchiffon;">Stars vs. the forces of Evil Cast
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Learn to use validators. [The HTML one](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) and [the CSS one](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have a bunch of typos. You don't close the `th` rule before the #EdenSher rule. Also, you need to remove the space between the `#` and `EdenSher`. I fixed up your code a bit, and you should also not have any spaces in your HTML tags.